# how to set "Date" header for http request

Tags: javascript, date, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I want to set the header for http request. The header name is "Date"

```
http_request.setRequestHeader("Date", headers.date);
```

But, when I see the request going out in firebug. I do not see the request header Date.

How do I set that?

Answer (score 6):

From a XMLHttpRequest, there are a set of headers that cannot be set.  Take a look at the spec for [setRequestHeader()](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method).  `Date` is one of these headers.

Also, if you look at the [WebKit source code](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/xml/XMLHttpRequest.cpp?rev=105076), you can see this in implementation.

```
bool XMLHttpRequest::isAllowedHTTPHeader(const String& name)
{
    initializeXMLHttpRequestStaticData();
    return !staticData->m_forbiddenRequestHeaders.contains(name) 
        && !name.startsWith(staticData->m_proxyHeaderPrefix, false)
        && !name.startsWith(staticData->m_secHeaderPrefix, false);
}
```

Comment: How do we enable the date header to be sent with each request fired from the browser? Should that be done in the server side?